# Подключение application.yml к чистому Spring

Tags: java, spring

Работаю в первый раз со Spring Framework, и столкнулся с тем, что не могу добавить свои источники property. Следующий код:

```
@Bean
public static YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlProperties() {
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    factory.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yml"));
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholder()
{
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setProperties(yamlProperties().getObject());
    return configurer;
}
```

Отрабатывает корректно, я могу спустить произвольную property в логгер, сами методы выполняются, однако в environment эти property не добавляются (т.е. `environment.getProperty()` не возвращает мне того значения, которое я могу получить через `yamlProperties.getObject().getProperty()`). ЧЯДНТ и как мне добавить свою конфигурацию в приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ЧЯДНТ

Лезете руками в `Environment`. Это кишочки, в которые не стоит без острой нужды ползти. Дока по [`Environment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) так и говорит:

> In most cases, however, application-level beans should not need to interact with the Environment directly

Если вы просто хотите дотянуться в коде до загруженных пропертей, заинжектите их в нужные бины через `@Value` и плэйсхолдеры:

```
public class SomeBean {

    @Value("${mybeans.foo}")
    private String foo;

    private String bar;

    @Value("${mybeans.baz}")
    private String baz;

    ...

}
```

Ad-hoc можно вытащить проперти из контекста так:

```
ctx.getBeanFactory().resolveEmbeddedValue("${mybeans.foo}")
```

---

PS. Начиная со Spring 3.1 рекомендуется пользоваться `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` вместо `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

---

PPS. Если все-таки очень хочется залить проперти в `Environment` с последующей стрельбой себе по ногам, можно сделать так:

```
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer prop = (PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer) ctx.getBean(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class);
Iterator<PropertySource<?>> iterator = prop.getAppliedPropertySources().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: Мда, был уверен, что все должно прогоняться через environment, и getProperty() в вариациях - единственная точка входа (и @Value проходит через нее же). Спасибо.